# What is the correct way of changing jcenter to mavenCentral?

Tags: gradle

I am working on an old project and Android Studio recommended me to update to mavenCentral().
I had this code:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And I have changed it to this one:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Now my question is, is it enough just changing jcenter() for mavenCentral() to update from jcenter to mavenCentral like I have done or should I make something else to update from jcenter to mavenCentral?

Comment: We don't know your criteria for "enough". The change that you made is sufficient to stop using JCenter, if that is what you are asking.

Comment: Is there anything not working? If everything works you are getting all your dependencies. But since `google` is first in the list it will look there first. Anyway this is a question about Gradle, not Java, Android or Android Studio.

Comment: @CommonsWare I just wanted to know if I have to change something else or it is okay like that, I mean, is the project "build.gradle" the only file where jcenter should be changed for mavenCentral or there are other files where I sould change something?

Comment: As sergpetrov notes, check all your `build.gradle` files. In a typical Android Studio project, your repositories are either listed in the project-level `build.gradle` file or elsewhere (`settings.gradle`), but it is possible for you to declare some in module-level `build.gradle` files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, it should be enough just changing `jcenter()` to `mavenCentral()` if your project is building successfully.
If not then you need to check what missing library in `mavenCentral` is failing your build. Then learn which ways you have to fix it, for some libs you will need to use `jitpack`, for others upgrade to a version (where the author migrated it to mavenCentral), or host it locally in the project, etc.

Also, don't forget to do it for `build.gradle` in your other modules (not only root).

Comment: --Also, don't forget to do it for build.gradle in your other modules (not only root).-- I don´t understand what other modules do you refer, I have only one module build.gradle an one project build gradle in my project and the setting.gradle. I have only seen that the repositories are located in the module build gradle, what other build.gradle do you refer? I am a little confused, I don´t understand what do you mean with "not only root", I would appreciate if you could explain it to me please

Comment: Under root, I mean project-level `build.gradle` (that is what you show in the question), but moreover you can have other modules (app, feature, or library modules) that have `build.gradle` in which it's possible to declare repositories as well. Just check all `build.gradle` files in your project. If you have `jcenter` in your single `build.gradle` then nevermind.
Read more about modules https://developer.android.com/studio/projects#ApplicationModules

Comment: @Eldestornillador Is it an answer to your question?